# Trouble working with openssl within Python

Tags: python, openssl, pickle

For starters, I can't use any 3rd party modules and my code must work with Python 2.4 due to this being a large enterprise environment and this tool must work on vanilla 2.4 python installs with no third party modules.

I'm writing a wrapper for openssl that will be used to retrieve/store encrypted data, mainly usernames/passwords and other authentication type data.

I'm writing the create module which creates a new, empty encrypted pickle file.

Flow is as follows:

Create a picklelized object in memory which is basically a dictionary object. (pickle.dumps)
Encrypt the resulting pickle string in memory (echo string | openssl.....)
Write this new string out as a pickle object. (pickle.dump)

Here is my current attempt:

```
def create(self, wallet, cipher=None, passphrase=None, **kawrgs):

    self.wallet = wallet
    rawdata     = None
    encdata     = None
    outfile     = None

    try:
        outfile = open(self.wallet, 'w')
    except Exception, e:
        raise OpenSSLWalletError("Failed to open '%s' for writing" % self.wallet, None, None, None)

    if passphrase:
        self.passphrase = "-k %s" % passphrase
    else:
        self.passphrase = "-k ''"

    if cipher:
        self.cipher = cipher

    try:
        rawdata = pickle.dumps(self.data)
        cmd = "echo -en '%s' | %s %s -a -salt %s" % (rawdata, self.openssl, self.cipher, self.passphrase)
        os_cmd  = shlex.split(cmd)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(os_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        encdata, stderr = proc.communicate()
        pickle.dump(encdata, outfile)
    except Exception, e:
        raise OpenSSLWalletError("Failed to create encrypted wallet '%s'" % self.wallet, cmd.rstrip(), None, stderr.rstrip())
```

I believe my problem is related to pickle adding newlines in the middle of the object which then breaks the openssl command:

Here is what the string looks like after pickle.dumps (basically this is just an empty dictionary fed to pickle):

```
self.data='{}'
'(dp0
.'
```

If I print out the cmd before it's fed to Popen, it looks like this:

cmd='echo (dp0

. | /usr/bin/openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -k '''

I've tried escaping the string, shell=True, shell=False, etc....

Anyone know any tricks or ways I can work around this? I assume stripping out the newlines from the pickle object will then break the pickle format and it won't be loadable, correct?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Forgot to add that "self.data = {}" is defined in the __init__ method of this class.

Comment: This doesn't help your situation but seeing pickle is bleh. I would recommend not using pickle. Because you have to unpickle. Can't use any other means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rawdata` can contain arbitrary binary data, I'd favor non-shell mode and pass the data directly into `openssl`'s standard input through `Popen.communicate()`.  The catch is you must also indicate to the `Popen` constructor that stdin should be piped.

```
rawdata = pickle.dumps(self.data)
cmd = [self.openssl, cipher, "-a", "-salt", "-k", passphrase or "''"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
encdata, stderr = proc.communicate(input=rawdata)
```

Also note that `encdata` will end in a newline.

Comment: Problem is openssl won't accept the data like this. That would be the equivalent of "openssl <args> < <data to be encrypted>

Comment: Also I *always* avoid Shell=True but in this case I tried it as a troubleshooting effort.

Comment: No, the data passed into the `input` parameter of `proc.communicate()` is passed to the standard input of the subprocess, which is what the `echo` was supposed to achieve.

Comment: Yea, in unix that is equivalent too "command < data" and openssl is hard-coded to not accept input like that. I tried it anyways... every possible permutation and it simply won't work. It will only allow you to cat/echo to the command. Granted, unless openssl was written this way for security reasons, the problem is the openssl command and it not being traditional unix-like... but then again, linux is riddled with non-conforming unix commands now days. This would probably work on Solaris or AIX.

Comment: Oh, sorry I see what you're saying now.  I missed the < bracket in the first comment.  It seems to be something odd about openssl; when I tried from the command line I had to send two EOFs to get it to run.  Anyway, I played around with it for a while and go it to work from Python.  I'd forgotten about also setting `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` in the `Popen` constructor.

Comment: You got this to work somehow? What version of python and openssl by chance?

Comment: Yes that was it... a stupid oversight, missing thbe stdin=subprocess.PIPE... thanks for catching that!

Comment: Took me a while too! Glad I could help.